# Model-implied covariance in a mediation / path model

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, mediation, path-model

I have a full mediation model described by the two equations

*Y = a<sub>y</sub> + b<sub>y</sub>M*

and

*M = a<sub>m</sub> + b<sub>m</sub>X*

How do I compute the model-implied covariance between Y and X? More generally, how do I compute the model-implied covariance between two indicators that are not directly connected?

Best

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself. It is *b<sub>m</sub>*b<sub>y</sub>*s<sub>x</sub>* with *s<sub>x</sub>* being the model-implied variance of X.